# Regex exclude partial text

Tags: regex

I always have an order number that could start with a letter or number.  e.g. 271546.  As the order ships out, if parts on the order don't ship, it creates a child order, e.g. 271546-1  What I want to do is create a regular expression that will find the 271546, but exclude the 271546-1 order.  e.g. it finds the -1.  If the order is bigger, we could see -2, -3, -4 variations of the original order number.  I've searched and searched but can't find a solution.  e.g. [-1]$ or ^([^-1]|-1([^-2]|-2([^-3]|$)|$)|$).*$

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does the full space of text look like? Just the order number? What language?

Comment: [^\w*$](https://regex101.com/r/CdAdaF/1/) ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to match? only a-z and 0-9 without the dash?  [`^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/NaSNMh/1)

Comment: Please provide some example inputs and outputs that illustrate the problem. For example if you have:

`271546` could you have multiple nested child orders?
`271546-1-1-1` etc, or will it always look like `271546-3`

In any case, is the expected output `271546` or `-1`?
re: "e.g. it finds the -1"

Comment: Hey thank you for the quick answers.  This one is getting close,  ^\w*$   My examples are 271546, 271456-1, 271456-2, 271456-3 and W-100716  When I use ^\w*$, it will find 271546, but excludes W-100716  . What I want it to bring back is only 271456 and W-100716

Comment: ^([a-zA-Z0-9]-)?\w+$ for the win!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Further refinement to support orders with leading letter and no hyphen

`^([A-Z]-?)?\d+$` will match 271546, W-100716, and Q696157, but not 271456-1, W-271456-3, or Q696157-2.

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bB8eq1/7) for an example and explanation.

#### Updated answer based on the clarified domain

`^([A-Z]-)?\d+$` will match 271546 and W-100716, but not 271456-1 or W-271456-3. You can add the lowercase letters if you want to the character range: `^([a-zA-Z]-)?\d+$` and it would then also match w-100716.

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bB8eq1/4) for an example.

#### Original Answer

Assuming you are just matching the order number, not trying to find an order number in some larger block of text, `^\w+` would work. If orders were just numbers, you'd use `^\d+`.

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bB8eq1/1/) for an example.

Comment: Note that `\w` will also match underscores, but if the domain doesn't include underscores `^\w+` will still work and is simpler than `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+`.

Comment: Hey thank you all, it matches as it should but what if we have a new order starting with Q696157 and no dash.  The script will find the # and the W orders but not the Q....

Answer (score 0):

If your value can start with a letter followed by a dash or only digits you could use:

[`^(?:[a-zA-Z]-)?\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/PhJKi6/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert the start of the line
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[a-zA-Z]-` Match a lower or uppercase followed by a dash
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional
- `\d+` Match one or more digits
- `$` Assert the end of the line

Note that you can use `[a-z]` with the `/i` case insensitive modifier.

```js
const strings = [
  "271546",
  "271456-1",
  "271456-2",
  "271456-3",
  "W-100716"
];
let pattern = /^(?:[a-z]-)?\d+$/i;

strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s + " ==> " + pattern.test(s));
});
```